# Identify each <td> element without id in CSS

Tags: html, css, popover

From the sample HTML below, is it possible in CSS to add a click event to each `<td>` element? or Identify in CSS which `<td>` element is clicked/hovered? Number of `<td>` inside a row can increase.

```
<table>
<tr class="tr-format">
    <td>
        Data1
        <div>PopUp</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        Data2
        <div>PopUp</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr-format">
    <td>
        Data1
        <div>PopUp</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        Data2
        <div>PopUp</div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am planning to display a PopUp or PopOver once a `<td>` is clicked, and those pop ups will contain different data for each `<td>`.

Comment: You don't define events in CSS, but in javascript. And in Javascript, the answer to your question would be YES.

Comment: where will be standing those extra hidden content ?

Answer (score 2):

Events like clicking on something are usually defined in Javascript, not CSS. Yes you can do it in CSS3, with [pseudo classes](http://www.screenfeed.fr/blog/css3-animation-on-click-without-js-0828/) and with new features like [animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp) but I advise you to look at how to do it in JS. [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/click/) is really easy to use for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

`.tr-format td`  use this selector for CSS. you need Javascript or Jquery to attach the events.

```
$('.tr-format td').on('click',function(){//do something here });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".tr-format td").each().on('click', function() { /**magic here**/ });
```

Comment: Hi i have a div with class name "pmu-popup" which is set to display:none. how do i display this div when a click event occurs?

i tried this inside the function $('.pmu-popup').slideToggle but it does not work.